# updating a game with Apk file?

Tags: updates, apk, side-loading

Ok im new to android as I used to be an iphone user so this question may not make any sense. Im used to jailbreaking but now I have a sg note 10.1 and im so lost with a few things. However, I downloaded an Apk file for this game/s. My question is if you have an Apk file can you update your game and do you lose your progress if you do? Someone explain to me all this stuff. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That process is called [Side Loading](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/side-loading/info) (I added the corresponding tag to your question, so you may simply click it for related questions). And yes, it can be done: All you'll have to do is to enable the [unknown-sources](/questions/tagged/unknown-sources) setting, and then access the `.apk` using a web [browser](/questions/tagged/browser) or file manager.

However: downloading apps from "dubious sources" carries a big risk, as they might include [malware](/questions/tagged/malware). Chances are especially high if you obtained that file from some "sharing site" like e.g. Mediafire or the like, where everybody can put everything. The risk you take that way is not worth the 99 cent saved by not buying the app on the playstore, so I would think twice before doing so. If you got the file from the developer's site, on the other hand, it should be as safe as if installed via the playstore.